# How do I construct MongoDB v3.6 aggregate call (vs. v3.4)?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this MongoDB function call which used to work fine in v3.4 (running on MongoDB Atlas):

```
WineUniversal.aggregate(
    [
        {"$match": query}, 
        {"$lookup": {
            "from": "wines", // name of the collection, not model or schema name
            "localField": "userWines",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "userWines"
        }},
        {"$unwind": "$userWines"},
        {"$match": {"userWines.scoreTotal":{"$gte":50}}},
        {"$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "lastUpdated": {"$first": "$lastUpdated"},
            "created": {"$first": "$created"},
            "category": {"$first": "$category"},
            "vintage": {"$first": "$vintage"},
            "winery": {"$first": "$winery"},
            "country": {"$first": "$country"},
            "region": {"$first": "$region"},
            "subRegion": {"$first": "$subRegion"},
            "appellation": {"$first": "$appellation"},
            "vineyard": {"$first": "$vineyard"},
            "varietal": {"$first": "$varietal"},
            "designation": {"$first": "$designation"},
            "additionalDetails": {"$first": "$additionalDetails"},
            "experReviewer1": {"$first": "$expertReviewer1"},
            "expertScore1": {"$first": "$expertScore1"},
            "experReviewer2": {"$first": "$expertReviewer2"},
            "expertScore2": {"$first": "$expertScore2"},
            "scoreCount": {"$first": "$scoreCount"},
            "averageScore": {"$first": "$averageScore"},
            "commonPrice": {"$first": "$commonPrice"},
            "wineryURL": {"$first": "$wineryURL"},
            "userWines":{"$push": "$userWines"}
        }},
        {"$sort": {"userWines.created": -1}},
        {"$limit": 300},
        {"$skip": 0}
    ]
).cursor({}).exec(function(err, universalWines) {
    console.log('DONE::::', universalWines);
    if (err) {
            console.log(err);
    } else {
        return res.json(universalWines);
    }
});
```

But MongoDB Atlas migrated everything to v3.6 and now this specific aggregate call of mine no longer works. I tried adding the `cursor()` function to the call which was showing up in the error log. But now I'm not getting any response or error for this aggregate call to my DB.

What am I missing? What change(s) do I need to make to get this working?

Comment: Mongoose version?

Comment: I just updated Mongoose to v5.9.10

Comment: Ok then remove the `.cursor()`. Everything will work perfect

Comment: That was it!! Thank you! Looks like I was chasing my tail here, updating modules, and fixing errors, all together at the same time.